# Como pegar o valor da porcentagem atual de um upload?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, upload

Estou trabalhando com `PHP`, mas imagino que isso possa ser feito só com `javascript/jQuery`. Quando faço um upload o navegador mostra na barra de status a porcentagem. Eu gostaria de pegar esse valor e criar a partir dele uma barra de progresso personalizada.

A barra eu sei fazer. Só não sei como pegar o valor atual da porcentagem. Como obtê-lo?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Usando o plugin de jquery ajaxform da para fazer dessa forma:

```
 $('form').ajaxForm({
        beforeSend: function() {
            status.empty();
            var percentVal = '0%';
            bar.width(percentVal);
            percent.html(percentVal);
        },
        uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
            var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
            bar.width(percentVal);
            percent.html(percentVal);
        },
        complete: function(xhr) {
            status.html(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
```

Baixar o plugin aqui http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started

Sem o plugin é meio complicado recomendo fortemente baixa-lo pois é muito útil para submeter forms via ajax entre outras coisas.

Answer (score 22):

No HTML5 é possível fazer isso adicionando um ouvinte `progress` à propriedade `upload` de um `XMLHttpRequest` (usado para fazer upload do arquivo via Ajax):

```
xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
    var pc = parseInt(100 - (e.loaded / e.total * 100));
    // Atualizar sua barra de progresso usando "pc"
}, false);
```

Fonte (e exemplo completo) em inglês: [How to Create Graphical File Upload Progress Bars in HTML5 and JavaScript](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-javascript-file-upload-progress-bar/). Essa funcionalidade, ao que parece, [é suportada por todos os browsers populares](http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2), na sua versão mais atual somente (ou seja, não funciona em versões mais antigas porém ainda muito utilizadas, como IE9 ou anterior).

Comment: Só um esclarecimento, esta é uma função disponível no [`XMLHttpRequest` Level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/).

Comment: A sua resposta deu certo pra mim, mas ontem passei o dia inteiro procurando e, em lugar algum, havia visto que o evento é para ser aplicado na propriedade "upload" do xhr. Até mesmo no MDN está documentado que o evento de progresso deve ser no próprio xhr. [Ver na MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Usando_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress)

Comment: @GiovanneAfonso Ambas as formas estão corretas. O [atributo `upload`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/#the-upload-attribute) é um [`XMLHttpRequestUpload`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/#xmlhttprequesteventtarget) que implementa [`EventTarget`](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#eventtarget) que possui o método [`addEventListener`](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#dom-eventtarget-addeventlistener). O próprio `XMLHttpRequest` também implementa `EventTarget`, provavelmente delegando a atribuição do ouvinte ao seu atributo `upload`.

Comment: No meu caso, quando eu vinculava o evento diretamente ao xhr, ele era chamado UMA vez após o término do upload com `event.loaded = [um número]` e `event.total = 0`. Mudando para o xhr.upload funcionou, o script está bem simples, talvez seja alguma configuração no servidor, mas seja como for, estou feliz que agora está funcionando.

Answer (score 7):

Como já mencionado, existem bibliotecas javascript que fazem o trabalho difícil para você. Em geral não vale a pena entrar em detalhes de baixo nível, pois provavelmente diferentes versões de diferentes navegadores serão usados você terá que lidar com inúmeros problemas de compatibilidade.

### Bibliotecas Javascript

Eu recomendo o uso do plugin [jQuery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload). Já usei em alguns projetos, inclusive suportando múltiplos uploads simultâneos mostrando os resultados em uma tabela. Veja o [demo aqui](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/).

Outra alternativa, principalmente para suportar navegadores mais antigos, é o [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/). Ele possui um *fallback* usando Flash, então quando o navegador não suportar os recursos avançados de upload, ele usará esta alternativa automaticamente.

### Implementação que depende do PHP

Por outro lado, se esta funcionalidade é importante para sua aplicação e ela vai receber uploads grandes, você pode usar a funcionalidade recente *Session Upload Progress* do PHP, disponível a partir da versão 5.4.

O *Session Upload Progress* não afeta a requisição com o upload, mas permite a você monitorar o upload através de uma variável colocada na sessão. Então você poderia fazer um Ajax a partir da página para recuperar a porcentagem do upload, passando o nome do campo por parâmetro. Veja o exemplo:

```
<?php
//nome do elemento da sessão contendo um array de informações de upload
$key = ini_get("session.upload_progress.prefix") .
        $_POST[ini_get("session.upload_progress.name")];

//recuperao vetor com informações de upload
$uploads_array = $_SESSION[$key];

//exibe as informações de um upload em específico
var_dump($uploads_array[$_POST["myField"]]);
?>
```

Para ativar a funcionalidade, habilite o parâmetro `session.upload_progress.enabled` no `php.ini`.

Veja a [documentação](http://www.php.net/manual/de/session.upload-progress.php) para maiores detalhes.

Comment: +1 por mencionar o jQuery File Upload do blueimp, já trabalhei com o plugin e é muito bacana.